# Prove that if $f(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n x^n$ has infinite radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove that if $f(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n x^n$ has infinite radius of convergence, and $g(x)= \sum_{0} b_{n} x^{n}$ has positive radius of convergence R, then, for each n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, $c_{n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{m} b_n^{(m)}$ converges absolutely and, for all x $\in$ (-R,R), $\sum c_{n} x^{n}$ converges to $f(g(x))$ and converges absolutely.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: What is $b_n^{(m)}$? How can one have $c_{n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\ldots$?

Comment: An infinite radius of convergence doesn't mean that that ratio test holds. Take $1+0+{x^2\over2}+0+{x^4\over4}+...$ as an example.

Comment: Nearly everything claimed for radii of convergence is not just wrong, you've got it backwards. If $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ exists, the limit is $0$ (but as @copper.hat said, that limit need not exist).

Answer (score 1):

There is something incorrect here.

Let $c(x) = f(g(x))$, and let $c(x) = \sum_k c_k x^k$.

Clearly $c_0 = c(0) = f(b_0) = \sum_k a_k b_0^k$.

We have $c'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$, and so
$c_1 = c'(0) = f'(b_0) b_1 = \sum_k k a_k b_0^{k-1} b_1$.

This does not match the formula given $\sum_k a_k b_1^k$.

For example, take $f(x) = 1+x$, $g(x) = {1 \over 1-x}-1$ for $|x|<1$ (in particular, $b_0 = 0$ and $b_k = 1$ for $k \ge 1$). Then
$c_1 = 1$, but the formula given above gives $a_0+a_1 = 2$.